# phpMyAdmin Hanngs when using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have phpMyAdmin 4.8.3 I use it everyday to query the main db table.
Today I tried to:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE list_id = 1227 LIMIT 2640`

and it keeps loadding until "Page Unresponsive"
I use it daily with no problems. It's just now and ONLY with `LIMIT` if I don't use `LIMIT` it works just fine even if I use many arguments and `ORDER BY RAND()`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use `LIMIT` in a query, PHPMyAdmin puts a Limit on its own. By default it is 30 rows per page (in older versions); in newer versions, it is 25 rows per page. It also provides a dropdown to change the number of rows per page upto **500** (this can crash sometimes, as 500 rows is a lot of data to render in one page).

[image]

Now, if you use a explicit `Limit` clause in the query; it will use your defined value. However, trying to render **2640** rows in a single web page is very high number. It will generally crash your browser, trying to load a lot of data. Just imagine the vertical scrolling you will be needed to do, to get to the bottom of the page. Moreover, it will increase load on your MySQL server as well, due to very high data packet being retrieved.