# Express JS with Sequelize take more time to execute query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have following Query which take **0.0039 seconds.** in phpMyAdmin. Same query take **6 second** in express js framework with Sequelize. Total records are **267121.**

```
SELECT pm.item_type,
       pm.product_type,
       pm.product_image,
       pm.product_id,
       pm.store_id,
       pm.item_type,
       pm.product_name,
       pm.product_description,
       spd.product_price
FROM product_master AS pm
JOIN store_products_detail spd ON pm.product_id = spd.product_id
WHERE spd.product_store_id IN(907)
```

I take following time in expressJS framework.

`query execution start time 2018-11-22T07:06:24.148Z`

`query execution end time 2018-11-22T07:06:30.249Z`

[image]

Question : Why expressJS framework take much time to execute query while in phpMyAdmin do not take much time.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because PHPMyAdmin has an implicit `LIMIT 25` (in newer version); so it fetches only 25 rows. While your application code is fetching all the rows, which is **all 267121** of them. This is quite big data packet to transfer. You can check this answer further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53030883/2469308

You should use `LIMIT ..` in your application code.

```
SELECT pm.item_type,
       pm.product_type,
       pm.product_image,
       pm.product_id,
       pm.store_id,
       pm.item_type,
       pm.product_name,
       pm.product_description,
       spd.product_price
FROM product_master AS pm
JOIN store_products_detail spd ON pm.product_id = spd.product_id
WHERE spd.product_store_id IN(907)
LIMIT 25
```

For performance, you will need the following indexes:

- `product_id` in `product_master` table
- `(product_id, product_store_id)` in `store_products_detail` table

Comment: You are right. Is there any way to optimize this query? or Only put `LIMIT` is option to optimization.

Comment: @Sadikhasan do you really want to fetch all the 200k+ rows in your application code. What are you trying to do with that ? If you want to do some calculations on all the data, you can rather do it at database end. Query in itself may be fast (if proper indexing is there); but fetching such large data packet is limited by other factors as well, such as network bandwidth etc.

Comment: @Sadikhasan added indexing details for this query to the answer

Comment: I added indexing details in my question

Comment: @Sadikhasan please define a composite index also (product_id, product_store_id). Also, as I said that indexing will still not solve the problem of fetching such a large data packet over network.